# Sub menu aligment issue

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I am using [this button drop down](http://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_js_dropdown_hover) located here. I need to make it look like the below picture

[image]

when you hover the drop down its flush with the left side of the `button` how can I make it flush to the right side and not the left.

```css
*.dropbtn {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}
.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #3e8e41;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Marc B i have tried adding float right.. no result

Comment: added picture of how i want it to look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just need to add `right:0` to `dropdown-content`, because by default the `position:absolute` it is aligned to left (like `left:0`)

```css
.dropbtn {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
 /* demo */
  left: 300px
}
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  right: 0
}
.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}
.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #3e8e41;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding `dir="rtl"` attribute to you dropdown div will solve your issue.

```
<div class="dropdown" dir="rtl">
```

Check [here](http://codepen.io/ArMikael/pen/rLwYBz) if this is the result you want to get?

Comment: In addition, I recommend you not to use * in CSS. It is very resource expensive and add unnecessary work to the browser. At least in your CSS you are for sure should exclude it.